# Cannot be converted to DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I try to filter the database of Firebase, but I got this error:

```
Error:(26, 107) error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to DatabaseReference
```

This is my code. It's running well if I remove `.startAt("test")`:

```
DatabaseReference listRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
   .getReference("question-answer")
   .startAt("test");`
```

I'm using FirebaseRecycleViewAdapter and I want to filter that view. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error:(26, 107) error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to DatabaseReference

You can check in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#startAt(java.lang.String)).
The method `startAt`returns a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) not a [`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference).

You have to use:

```
Query listRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
   .getReference("question-answer")
   .startAt("test");
```

You can use your `RecyclerView` by passing a `Query` instead of a normal `DatabaseReference`.

```
Query listRef = ....;
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<XX, XXViewHolder>(XX.class,
            R.layout.xxx_recycler_item, EXXViewHolder.class, listRef) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks it's work, but it's only search from the beginning of the text.. it's work if i have data like this `test hello world`, but not working with this data `hellow test world`

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
Query query  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
   .getReference("question-answer")
   .startAt("test");
```

query is a parameter for the recycleradapter so it will work
because DatabaseReference extends Query

Comment: thanks for the answer its work, but is it possible to search text in the middle of the data ? it's still not work if my data like this `hello test world`